# Ways a program might detect whether NULL is defined with integer or pointer type?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

C allows `NULL` to be defined to any *null pointer constant*, in other words, any *integer constant expression* that evaluates to 0, or such an expression cast to `void *`. My question concerns whether the choice of definition really matters, i.e. whether an otherwise-correct program might depend on which definition is used. For the purpose of this question, I'd like to ignore issues like `NULL` being passed to variadic functions or functions lacking prototypes, since I've already dealt with it separately. Let's assume `sizeof NULL == sizeof(void *)` and `sizeof NULL == sizeof(T)` for some integer type `T`, so that `sizeof` is not sufficient to answer the question of whether `NULL` has pointer type.

Obviously, C11 provides a way to distinguish the type of `NULL` or any other expression: the `_Generic` keyword.

C99 also provides one obscure way that seems to be reliable:

```
int null_has_ptr_type()
{
    char s[1][1+(int)NULL];
    int i = 0;
    return sizeof s[i++], i;
}
```

Are there any other methods by which the type of `NULL` may be determined by a conforming C program? Any that work in C89?

Comment: `char c = NULL;` generates compiler warnings if `NULL` is of type `void *` (so the cast is present).

Comment: Does the function `null_has_ptr_type` really work? It returns 0 in both case on my computer.

Comment: `return sizeof s[i++], i;` will return i.

Comment: I get the same as @Kirilenko...

Comment: You need a C compiler with C99 support including VLAs and  proper implementation of sizeof in that case. If `s` is a VLA, `i++` is evaluated, otherwise it's not. And `s` will be a VLA if NULL is a pointer, not if it's an int. Or something like that... GCC gives different warnings in both cases. @Kirilenko

Comment: @Mat: Seems to be right. With `clang` it prints the correct result.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: This question is tagged C, not C++. :-)

Comment: @Kirilenko: I'd be interesting in knowing which compiler/version gave the wrong answer.

Comment: @R.: `gcc 4.4.5`, whereas `clang 2.8` works as expected.

Comment: I just confirmed that gcc 4.6 works correctly, so the issue must have been fixed somewhere between 4.4.5 and 4.6.3. A lot of correctness issues were addressed in the 4.5 series so it was probably somewhere in that range that it was fixed. Good to know that some still-widely-used gccs give the wrong result, though.

Comment: @R..: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/c99status.html states "broken" VLA support. 4.5 says it's ok. (4.6.1 works.)

Comment: @R. the C99 solution is really nice, are you the author of this code snippet?

Comment: @ouah: I'm the author of that specific example, but the concept is existing lore and I don't recall the source.

Comment: @R. and do you plan to practically use this `null_has_ptr_type` function or is that only to answer this question: *...whether the choice of definition really matters...*?

Comment: @ouah: I have no plans to use it except as an example. The real usefulness of this question is as part of evaluating *whether the definition of `NULL` matters* to application compatibility, and if so, in which ways.

Comment: "I'd like to ignore issues like NULL being passed to variadic functions or functions lacking prototypes, since I've already dealt with it separately." -->  Is that dealt with in a SO post?  What reference, if any?  (I'd like to avoid a dupe question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through the question, answers, and comments, I think we established:

1. The C11 way is easy (`_Generic`).
2. The C99 way is fairly unreliable due to buggy compilers.
3. Stringifying approaches are a dead-end due to `typedef`.
4. No other approaches were found.

So the answer seems to be that there's no reliable pre-C11 method, and seemingly no valid pre-C99 method.

Answer (score 4):

Get the string definition of NULL and then do an as complete check as you want.  Here is a very simple minded one:

```
#define XSTR(x) #x
#define STR(x) XSTR(x)

if (STR(NULL)[0] == '(') {
   ...
}
```

But I don't know how you'll handle a `__null` which can come out from that.

Comment: @R.., there was a reason for which I proposed a **very simple minded one** ;

Comment: Does this work for arbitrary levels of macro indirection? e.g. `#define NULL _NULL1`, `#define _NULL1 _NULL2`, `#define _NULL2 _NULL3`, ..., `#define _NULL999 0`? I think not..

Comment: @R..: It seems to have been established that the definition *can* be detected in theory.  Is there a practical need for a robust solution?

Comment: @R.., that's not a problem (an argument is fulled expanded before passing it to another macro), two levels are needed because it is used verbatim with # and ##.

Comment: @Oli: Nope, actually I'm more interested in ways applications might *inadvertently* depend on the definition.

Comment: @R.., as you excluded variadic functions (where the difference can lead to UB), I don't see a plausible case for inadvertent dependence.  And I'd expect it to be addressed or at least folklore by now if there was one (especially that `(void*)0` is common for C implementation and non conforming for C++).

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you stringify the macro and look at the string?

```
# include <stddef.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

# define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_AUX(x)
# define STRINGIFY_AUX(x) #x

int main(void)
{
  const char *NULL_MACRO = STRINGIFY(NULL);

  if (strstr("void", NULL_MACRO) != NULL)
    puts("pointer");
  else
    puts("integer");
}
```

It correctly prints `"integer"` if you add this (usually `NULL` has pinter type):

```
# undef NULL
# define NULL 0
```

`NULL` cannot be something like `(int) ((void *) 0)` because the standards doesn't state that a null pointer constant converted to an integer type is still a null pointer constant.

Furthermore, the standard also say this about *integer constant expressions* (C11, 6.6/6):

> An *integer constant expression*<sup>117)</sup> shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, **`sizeof`** expressions whose results are integer constants, **`_Alignof`** expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the **`sizeof`** or **`_Alignof`** operator.

**EDIT**: actually this doesn't work with things like:

`# define NULL (sizeof(void *) - sizeof(void *))`

(thanks for noticing) and this cannot be checked in a trivial way as the OP needs, a little bit of work (simple parsing) is required.

**EDIT 2**: and there are also `typedef` as comment correctly pointed out.

Comment: @AProgrammer good point... but what about `# define NULL ((int) 0)` or `(0)` if you look at the first character? :) Thanks anyway, I will correct it with another test.

Comment: In theory this approach could work, but it's highly nontrivial.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if it can work or not. See my comment on AProgrammer's answer.

Comment: @netcoder: That's the other way around. An integer constant expression with value 0 is still a null pointer constant when you cast it to `void *`. But casting a pointer to an integer type never yields an integer constant expression.

Comment: @effeffe, I'm not sure it is a very good point, it was mean more as a joke. I've only see in practice 3 definitions: `0`, `0L` and `(void*)0`.

Comment: @R.. macros are fully expanded so I think this could work now. But yes, it's not so trivial... couldn't find anything better for the moment.

Comment: @AProgrammer I think the answer is in C11 6.6/6, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Your args to `strstr` are backwards. :-) And the check is buggy. `#define NULL (sizeof(void *)-sizeof(void *))`.

Comment: Obviously, the plausible difficult case to handle is `#define NULL __null` where `__null` is an intrinsic of the compiler.

Comment: @R.. thanks for arguments... and let me think about the buggy test. :) (man you're the evil, that's really weird)

Comment: @AProgrammer but if the standard says that the macro has to be a null pointer constant, shouldn't it expand to such an expression in the end? Otherwise, wouldn't it be illegal?

Comment: @effeffe, it seems to me that saying that __null is a integer constant expression (casted to void* or not) is a conforming extension and there is nothing preventing the use of extensions in the definition of standard macros (there are a few which probably can't be defined without relying on implementation defined things, the var args stuff for instance). BTW, GCC does use such a definition for NULL in C++.

Comment: @effeffe: Indeed, I think strictly speaking, using `__null` may be non-conforming, since the standard is very strict on what constitutes a null pointer constant and does not seem to allow additional implementation-defined ones.

Comment: @AProgrammer it seems you're right about C++ (I tried it now), but is this really conforming in C? Where the C standard say that this is conforming? If my program receive "__null", which is not a null pointer constant, I think this is illegal.

Comment: @R.., the standard just says that *NULL expands to an implementation defined null pointer constant*, I don't see where it prevent an implementation to consider `__null` as an implementation defined null pointer constant.

Comment: At least in C, per 6.3.2.3, "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant." `__null` is neither an integer constant expression with the value 0, nor one cast to `void *`, so it's not a null pointer constant.

Comment: @AProgrammer there *"implementation defined"* means that it can be `0`, `(int) 0`, `(void *) 0` and so on, but the meaning of *"null pointer constant"* is well defined and doesn't lead to implementation-defined behavior. It's implementation-defined *which* of all the possibile null pointer constant is used.

Comment: By the way, I think the problem is actually a lot easier than I thought. First skip all initial `(` characters and whitespace, then check that the next character is `v`.

Comment: @R.. `# define NULL (1 ? (void *) 0 : (void *) 0)`? (no wait, maybe this is no more a constant expression, have to check this)

Comment: @R.., saying that `__null` is a null pointer constant is for sure a conforming extension (the standard says nothing about `__null` excepted that it is reserved for the implementation).  Then I see nothing preventing the use of a conforming extension in the definition of `NULL`.

Comment: @R.. my previous comment was wrong. Anyway, you're lucky, there are no standard integer types beginning with v :) I think your idea could work and it's quite easy.

Comment: The problem is that the definition of "null pointer constant" is very strict. It's not "an integer constant expression with value 0, or such an expression cast to void *, or another implementation-defined null pointer constant". The **only** way it's allowed to have pointer type is by applying the `(void *)` cast directly, as the final operator, to an integer constant expression with value 0.

Comment: @R.. Checking for `'v'` need not work: `typedef void *GenericPointer;`.

Comment: @DanielFischer if we add `typedef` to this problem I think there is absolutely no way to retrieve the type of `NULL` in pre-C11 standard C, right? It could be everything.

Comment: @effeffe The function in the question works for conforming C99 compilers. But pre-C99, I don't see any foolproof runtime way. Of course, in any sensible implementation, you have either `(void*)0` or `0` [possibly with a type suffix on the `0`], so no real problem. But if we drop the sensibility restriction ...

Comment: @DanielFischer by the way, is really legal to use `typedef` types in a null pointer constant? The standard says that it has to be an integer or a pointer-to-void, not *"... or an equivalent type"* as it says in other parts of standard like C11-5.1.2.2.1/p1 about `main()` (`typedef` is also mentioned in the foot-note). Maybe I'm missing some "general rule" somewhere in the standard... damn, before you came we had a standard compliant nonsense-proof solution. :)

Comment: But a `typedef` is not just an equivalent type, it's another name for the same type, so casting to `GenericPointer` _is_ casting to `void*`.

Comment: Yes, I think `typedef` puts the nail in the coffin for this approach. There's no way it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one obscure way: If the program uses the expression `&*NULL`, this won't compile with `NULL` having integer type but will if `NULL` has pointer type.

C99 has wording for this special case:

> If the operand [of the `&` operator] is the result of a unary `*`
>   operator, neither that operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and
>   the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on
>   the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue.

The constraints on the operators aren't violated: the operand of `&` is the result of the unary `*` operator, and the operand of the unary `*` operator has pointer type (as we are assuming `NULL` is defined that way).

Comment: I think the question is looking for something that will compile whether `NULL` is of pointer or integer type. `NULL+NULL` compiles if and only if `NULL` is of integer type.